# What is the big o notation of this code? Is it O(n^2) or O(n)?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Here, the code check if list1 contains some elements of list2?

```
result = []
    for item in list1:
        if item not in list2:
            result.append(item)
```

I think that the complexity will be O(n^2) because the (x in s) function is considered as inner loop right?

Comment: [Try it and see](https://tryitands.ee)

Answer (score 1):

Your time complexity is O(n). If you are using hashset for the set2 variable, the 'in' operation performs constant in average.

If you use two list, then the time complexity is O(nm) where n = len(list1) and m = len(list2)

Comment: You mean that the (x in s) function takes O(n), so in total the code will run in O(n)?

Comment: If I'm searching into two lists it also will be O(n)?

Comment: According to the question, there are `2` lists so the time complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Wow, if you are using two list, then your time complexity is O(n^2) or O(nm) in a more generic way there m is the lenght of your second list

Answer (score 0):

If `set2` is an actual `set` or `dict` it's **`O(len(list1))`** because `x in some_set` will be (amortised) `O(1)`.

If `list2` is a list, then it's going to be **`O(len(list1) * max_len(list2))`** because `x in some_list` will need to run through the list in `O(len(some_list))`. So if both lists can be up to `n`, then it's going to be `O(n^2)`.

Comment: If I'm searching into two lists it will be O(n)?

Comment: @MohamadEmad read again  If you have two lists, it's going to be O(n^2). If you have a list and a set, it's O(n)

Answer (score 0):

`in` operator's complexity is based on what's the type of your list.
if your lists is python's `list` type, in [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) we can see (x in s) with list in python has the complexity of O(n)

so if your list1 has n element, list2 has m element, your code's complexity will be O(n.m)